# I need to create an SPD2010 Designer workflow that will run when a date range is equal to Today -6

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using SPD and SharePoint 2010 and I have a list where Project Manager's enter weekly updates and I'm looking for a way to automate a reminder to them.  Currently we have a field called "Date PM Updated" (there are other fields that are edited by other project team members, so simply using the Modified field will not work).  I'd like to create a workflow that will be manually initiated once a week (I'll get into automation once this workflow is successfully up and running - not a big deal to do it manually for now).
The criteria would be: If "Date PM Updated" is between today and today -6, then send e-mail to PM Assigned.
Seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out how to create the today -6.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  Maybe I've been thinking about it too long and I'm missing something simple.
Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Use the Add Time to Date action. Make it -6 days to Today (click the date hyperlink, click the 3 dotted button and select Current date)

Step 2: add 2 if value equals value conditions. Configure one to be if current item:date pm updated is greater than or equal to date variable above. Configure the second to be and if current item: pm updated date less than or equal to today. The action then would be to email the user.

Comment: PirateEric - Thank you very much for this...I was not aware of the Add Time to Date action.  I've built this out and tested it successfully.  Your help is much appreciated!